# ng-disabled not working in IE

Tags: angularjs

```
<div>
 <p>hello</p>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="somefunction()" >
</div>
```

In controller function

```
$scope.somefunction = function(){
 return true;
}
```

My code looks like this.

ng-disabled working fine in chrome and Firefox.

In IE11, if I double-click the checkbox its checked.

please let me know , why ng-disabled failed in IE.

I tried with ng-readonly , Its is also failed

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of angular are you using ?

Comment: latest version i.e Angular 1.2.12.  In IE 11 , checkbox is disabled, but if double click on it , It is selected.

Comment: Can you share the document mode you use in the html, like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

Answer (score -1):

You can make class in Css for example:

```css
.disabled-class{pointer-events: none; color: gray;}
```

And after this you can use this class in ng-class